# ActiveMQ Artemis + queue filter

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.15.0 and have master/slave configuration with following address:

```xml
<address name="TestTopic">
   <multicast>
      <queue name="TestQueue" />
   </multicast>
</address>
```

After starting master/slave pair I have add filtered as below:

```xml
<address name="TestTopic">
    <multicast>
        <queue name="TestQueue">
            <filter string="archive IS NULL OR archive &lt;&gt; true" />
        </queue>
    </multicast>
</address>
```

After adding `filter`, when I processed a message with the JMS header `archive` with value `true` the filter will not work as expected. Also I have executed following cli command to update filter but still no luck.

```
artemis queue update --user admin --password admin --url tcp://localhost:61617 --filter "archive IS NULL OR archive &lt;&gt; true"
```

To resolve the problem I need to restart the ActiveMQ Artemis server. Is it possible for the filter to work without restarting? Find my brokers on [GitHub](https://github.com/bhaveshkharwa/artemis-filter-issue).

Comment: yes, I have tried with latest artemis 2.15.0 and still getting same behavior.

Comment: I just tested this in the Artemis test-suite, and everything worked as expected. The filter was applied properly. Can you provide the log from when you updated `broker.xml`? It should log details about the resources it's re-deploying when you modify it.

Comment: have you tested with two master and two slave? I have test with single master and slave and it is working fine but when I test with two master and two slave then it will not work

Comment: Are you changing the filter on both masters or just one of them? You have to change it on *both*.

Comment: Yes, I have changed filter on both the masters and process the message

Comment: Can you provide the log from when you updated broker.xml? It should log details about the resources it's re-deploying when you modify it.

Comment: I have added artemis log in github: https://github.com/bhaveshkharwa/artemis-filter-issue/tree/master/logs

Comment: The logs look OK. Could you work up a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: For testing, you can use attached broker.xml (master and slave without filter) and first send message to topic and then apply filter in broker.xml and then send message. By this way you can reproduce this issue

Comment: I know I can set it all up myself. I was looking for something more automated. If you don't have anything like that or can't be bothered to create then I suppose I'll get around to testing this when I have a chance.

Comment: Thank you. Please do the needful